# CLOB in oracle not allowing to insert data more than 4000 chars

Tags: java, oracle11g, clob

Below is my table

```
create table MY_LOG(SQNO NUMBER, CLOB_FLD CLOB);
```

Below is my insert statement executed from java side

```
stmt.execute(new StringBuilder(
                "INSERT INTO MY_LOG VALUES ('").append(logMessage.getNo()).append("','").append(logMessage.getStackTrace()).append("')"));
```

the stacktrace is too large i.e more than 4000 characters. So Its throwing

```
SQL Error: ORA-01704: string literal too long
01704. 00000 -  "string literal too long"
*Cause:    The string literal is longer than 4000 characters.
*Action:   Use a string literal of at most 4000 characters.
           Longer values may only be entered using bind variables.
```

Is there any function or procedure inbuilt or is there anything i can do to make this work properly ??

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use PreparedStatement, create a CLob with Connection.createCLob, put your text into CLob with CLob.setString, set PreparedStatement parameter with PreparedStatement.setCLob

Comment: Tried creating connection.createClob(). Throwing exception.           Caused by: java.lang.AbstractMethodError: oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleConnection.createClob()Ljava/sql/Clob;

Comment: You need ojdbc6.jar , createClob is since 1.6